Track progress of horizontal scroll (x) inside of a div using js
I'm trying to create a progress bar showing how much is scrolled inside a div on the x axis but don't get it to work. status now is that the "data-progress" div is not getting any of the style at all. What am i doing wrong here? The html is using Tailwind css to apply the styles, so don't bother those. They are correct. I'ts the JS i'm struggling with.
HTML
<section class="grid-layout">
  <div class="col-span-10 col-start-2 py-50 overflow-x-scroll scroll-smooth" data-scroller>
    <div class="inline-grid grid-flow-col gap-25">
      <div class="flex bg-primary" style="width: 600px;">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="flex bg-primary" style="width: 300px;">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="flex bg-primary" style="width: 500px;">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="flex bg-primary" style="width: 700px;">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-10 col-start-2 relative">
    <div class="absolute inset-0 h-2 w-full bg-transparent">
      <div class="absolute z-10 inset-0 h-full w-0 bg-primary" data-progress>
    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

JS
export default class Scroller {
  constructor() {
    this.element = document.querySelector('[data-scroller]')
    this.progress = document.querySelector('[data-progress]')

    this.element.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
      const pixelScrolled = this.element.scrollX
      const elementWidth = this.element.offsetWidth
      const scrollable = e.scrollLeft

      const pixelsToPercentage = (pixelScrolled / (elementWidth - scrollable)) * 100

      this.progress.style.width = Math.round(pixelsToPercentage) + '%'
    })
  }
}


new Scroller()

